# Kotlin and generics: How to filter values

Tags: java, kotlin, generics, types, rx-java

I have created a WebSocket class that emits protobuf (Square Wire) messages. I want to have an extension function that filters only the messages I want. The usage would be something like this:

```
fun main() {
    val webSocket: WebSocket
    // ... configure web socket

    webSocket.filterMessages<CreateContactResponse>()
        .subscribe {
            println("Create contact response received")
        }
    webSocket.filterMessages<DeleteContactResponse>()
        .subscribe {
            println("Delete contact response received")
        }
}
```

and below is the extension function I wrote. I have added comments with the errors the IDE shows me.

```
fun <MESSAGE : Message<*, *>> Websocket.filterMessages(): Flowable<MESSAGE> {
    observeMessages()
        .filter { it is MESSAGE } // Error: Cannot check for instance of erased type: MESSAGE
        .map { it as MESSAGE } // Error: Unchecked cast: Message<*, *> to MESSAGE
}
```

Can you guys please explain me how can I make that work as expected?

Answer (score 4):

`MESSAGE` must be [reified](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters), so you must write it as

```
inline fun <reified MESSAGE : Message<*, *>> 
 Websocket.filterMessages() : Flowable<Message> { ... }
```